# How to handle Meteor post-login deep linking

Tags: meteor, authorization, deep-linking

An unauthorized user tries to load `my.app/path/to/auth/only/view` but Meteor redirects them to server root `my.app/` for login. How do I redirect that user post-login to `/path/to/auth/only/view` ?

I'm using kadira:flow-router, accounts-password, useraccounts:core.

Comment: an alternate strategy might be to suppress the logged out redirect so the user never leaves `my.app/path/to/auth/only/view`, but just the view changes from unauth to auth state

Comment: this solution looks interesting: https://medium.com/@satyavh/using-flow-router-for-authentication-ba7bb2644f42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hah, i just removed this from my main template. problem solved.

```
Template.globalLayout.onCreated(function () {
    Deps.autorun(function () {
        if(Meteor.user()===null){FlowRouter.go('/');}
    )}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Register on `onLogin` callback (http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin) that calls `FlowRouter.go()`.

Comment: that's handy, but the biggest problem for me is to capture the auth/session redirect event, so I can note the original request route beforehand